# How to add shell script to jenkins pipeline

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below shell script:

```
du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -20 |
while IFS= read -r line;do
        DIR=`echo $line | awk '{print$2}'`
        Rep=`cat $DIR/repository-config |grep 'project\|repo' |  tr '\n' ' '`
        Size=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' `
        echo $Size $Rep
done
```

How can I run it thought Execute shell in Jenkins? I need also to add ssh command to the env (no need for a password).
Note I don't want to connect to the env and run this shell, but directly from Excecue shell box

[image: Execute shell]

Comment: I may be missing something, but the option of pasting your script into the box doesn't work for some reason?

Comment: No. I don't know how to combine it with the ssh command: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -n XXXXX@YYYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong your are using a Freestyle job and not a pipeline job.
Anyway, I think you have to try the following :

`ssh -t XXXXX@YYYYY << 'EOF'
du -sh /bbhome/shared/data/repositories/* |sort -h |tail -20 |
while IFS= read -r line;do\
        DIR=`echo $line | awk '{print$2}'`\
        Rep=`cat $DIR/repository-config |grep 'project\|repo' |  tr '\n' ' '`\
        Size=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}' `\
        echo $Size $Rep\
done
EOF`

I've escaped the code inside your while loop using \, if it's doesn't works you can use ; instead.

If you want help for using a pipeline job, let me know but i might be a bit more complex.